# When using Sequel ORM; when to use Core or Model?

Tags: ruby, orm, sequel

I'm looking to expand my ruby knowledge beyond scripting, test code and file parsers by writing some web services. I'm thinking of using [sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html) as an ORM.

What advantages are there to using Sequel Core or Sequel Model? What should I be looking out for? What rules of thumb are there for picking one or the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sequel core is more a less a version of SQL in ruby.  It's good for reporting, data processing, or when you want to manipulate sets of objects at once.

Sequel::Model is an object-relational mapper, allowing you to assign behavior to specific types of rows.  If most of your work is dealing with individual rows instead of groups of rows, you will probably want to use models.

If you are unsure, start with Sequel Model.  Sequel Model is built on top of Sequel core, so you have all of the power of core datasets when using models.